# Using Perl, How do I save an image from an external script (PHP) URL

Tags: image, perl, url, save

I have a Perl script that needs to retrieve an image from an external URL and save it locally.  In some cases, the URL is a direct URL to a PNG file and my code works perfectly to capture the image data and save it locally.

My Perl code looks like this:

```
$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
$ua->agent("MyAgent");
$response = $ua->get($iconpath);
$content = $response->decoded_content(charset => 'none');

open(ICONFILE, ">$localimagefile");
binmode(ICONFILE);
print ICONFILE $content;
close(ICONFILE);
```

But in some cases, the URL for the image on the external site (iconpath) is a PHP script, like this:

```
http://forecast.weather.gov/DualImage.php?i=sct&j=hi_tsra&jp=30
```

In this case, the local image file is created, but it's zero bytes. When I try to dump $content after the request, it's empty and it's length is zero.  For a direct URL to a PNG file, this same code works perfectly and saves a valid copy of the image file on the server.

I've tried various methods using wget, curl, backticks, and LWP:Simple (getstore), but I always have the same empty file results with the images generated externally using the PHP URL.

Any ideas how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I use `$ua->get($url, :content_file   => $filename);` to trigger a PHP script and get the content it serves. Try that?

Comment: Thanks.  I just tried it and it did exactly the same thing.  Creates the local file but the size is zero.  :(

Comment: I just got to try it out with the url you provide -- and I get the image, using your code (also with bare `$response->decoded_content`), with or without `binmode`.

Comment: Fascintating.  So perhaps something different about the server making the call?  I even tried setting the request headers so they'd match the request headers sent by my browser (which gets the correct image back), but that didn't help either.  I thought for a moment that perhaps my server was being blocked, but it works for a regular direct PNG file URL, so their server isn't blocking my server.  I wish they'd return an error message indicating why the call failed, but no such luck  I get absolutely nothing back  Even "is_success" is true when the call returns...

Comment: Just tried it again with the image URL above and it worked!  First I tried it in a simple test script with nothing but the code above and it worked, so I restored my main app to that code and it also worked, saving the image using:
    $ua->get($iconlink, ':content_file' => "$cachefile");
But then I tried it with a different PHP icon link returned from the weather.gov API tonight:

    http://forecast.weather.gov/DualImage.php?i=hi_tsra&amp;j=hi_shwrs&amp;ip=20&amp;jp=30

And this link does not work in my small test app or my main app.  Same as before it creates a zero-byte file.

Comment: Actually, the new "bad" link above (returned from the weather API) doesn't even work in my browser, so I have no idea what's going on now!

Comment: Heh. One of those things.  This new link that you provide in the comment -- I don't see it in my browser either.  So I guess you can write it off as a bad link. Can you just use the one that works?

Comment: Ok, I think I just figured it out.  When I dumped the link(s) returned from the weather.gov API before calling the ->get, it printed to the browser and I copied it from there and pasted it here, and it looked fine.  But I just checked the actual data returned from their API and and the link has the "&" character replaced by the HTML entity code & amp ; (ignore spaces -- added so it shows up here).  Anyway, if I replace the entities with actual ampersand characters before calling the ->get with that URL, it works!  Sorry about that - I should have noticed it earlier... :(

Comment: Ah, good! Lesson learned -- and it was good for me to hear about it, too. Consider posting this as an answer, for those who come along with a similar problem.  You can accept it, too, so the question is listed as answered.  This is completely OK and actually encouraged -- see ['Can I answer my own question`](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Thanks, I will. I don't think I have enough points to get the "answer your own question box"  (since it doesn't appear for me now) and I have to wait 48 hours to accept my response above. But I was hoping that posting what I had found could potentially help someone with a similar issue in the future.

Comment: I think that the box is about posting the answer along with the question, as you are ask it. People sometimes do that, to highlight an issue that they think is worth attention. You can post an answer (no rep needed), and then you need to wait for 48 hours, after which you can accept it like you would any other. The difference is that you don't get the (2) points for accepting and that it doesn't float to the top of all answers. I wouldn't push that when there are good answers but when you figure it out and there aren't good answers I think that it's a good thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the actual data returned from the weather API had the "&" character replaced by the HTML entity code & amp ; (ignore spaces -- added so it shows up here).  I didn't notice this when I dumped the returned URL to the browser since it simply displayed as a regular ampersand (&).  The simple solution was to replace the HTML entities with actual ampersand characters before calling the ->get with that URL, which works perfectly and returns the image data or saves it directly when using ":content_file => $filename" in the ->get call.